# Metal Texture is darker than original image

Tags: ios, swift, macos, image-processing, metal

I am writing some code for a little program in macOS to play with image processing with Metal Performance Shaders. For some reason, the code below produces an image that looks significantly darker than the original.

The code simply takes a texture, performs a little guassian blur on it, and then outputs the image to the MTKView. I cannot figure out why the resulting image is so dark, though.

```
import Cocoa
import Metal
import MetalKit
import CoreGraphics
import MetalPerformanceShaders


class ViewController: NSViewController, MTKViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: MTKView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setup the Metal Pipeline
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    imageView.device = device
    imageView.framebufferOnly = false
    imageView.isPaused = true
    let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
    let gaussian = MPSImageGaussianBlur(device: device, sigma: 2)
    let data = imageData(name:"sample", type:"jpg")

    let inputTexture = try! MTKTextureLoader(device: device).newTexture(data: data, options: nil)

    gaussian.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: inputTexture, destinationTexture: (imageView.currentDrawable?.texture)!)
    commandBuffer.present(imageView.currentDrawable!)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}

func imageData(name: String, type: String) -> Data {
    let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)!
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: urlpath)
    var data : Data? = nil
    do{ try data = Data(contentsOf: url)}
    catch{print("Couldn't set data.")}
    return data!
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

}
func draw(in view: MTKView) {
}
```

}

What I did try to do on my own was to see if maybe for some reason the pixel format of the view being different mattered, as my input texture is a `RGBA8UNorm_sRGB` while `imageView.currentDrawable.texture` is a `BGRA8UNorm`, however all of the examples of MPS don't really care what this pixel format is.

Input Image: [image]
Weird Darker Output Image: [image]

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens if you don't do the Gaussian blur on it? Is it still dark?

Comment: @DaveWeston indeed it is, even performing linear transformations on the image like `MPSBilinearScaling` or `MPSTranspose` results in the darker colored image.

Comment: Ugh, of course -__- it was the SRGB!! If you give `MTLTextureLoader` the option `[MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : false]`. I just feel silly for asking my question and then figuring it out later. I'll leave it up in case other people run into the same thing, it seems like a common instance with the Texture Loader!

Comment: @DavidSacco Please write an answer for the question which explains the issue and accept it afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of darkening usually means that gamma correction is set up wrongly. Like you said in a comment, it can be fixed by option

```
[MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : false]
```