# How do I change the pixelFormat in Metal?

Tags: macos, metal

If I try anyting other than `bgra8Unorm`, it will crash, saying,

> -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder validateFramebufferWithRenderPipelineState:]:1192: failed assertion `For color attachment 0, the render pipeline's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB) does not match the framebuffer's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm).'

How do I change the framebuffer's pixelFormat then? I want to be able to do this:

```
PipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm_srgb
```

Instead of this

```
PipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
```

Again, this is an attempt to fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761448/metal-rendering-odd-darker-textures-even-with-mtktextureloader-option-srgb-fa) stupid bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the MetalView defined here:

```
var MetalView: MTKView {
    return view as! MTKView
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad:`

```
MetalView.colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm_srgb
```

Then I can do this:

```
PipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm_srgb
```

I figured it out myself yay!